Error Message When Updating. libnautilus-extension4:amd64 is missing final newline
Error Message When Updating.
I have tried one listed solution, but it does not work.
The problem is this...
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list file for package 'libnautilus-extension4:amd64' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:

There is no info here that can be used to offer any help. Please read the info on this link and edit the question and add some details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
